# How to use like operator within LDAP query?

Tags: java, ldap

I would like to use Like operator within my LDAP query and find any name starting with the String Name. (something like [Name = Mike*]) but apparently it doesn't work. 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
public List<String> findByName(String Name) {
    LdapQuery query = query().where("objectclass").is("top")
            .and("Name").like(Name);

    return ldapTemplate.search(query, new NameAttributesMapper());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [LdapQueryBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/query/LdapQueryBuilder.html) and [LikeFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/filter/LikeFilter.html) states that you have to use the `*` explicitly in the query, so if you're looking for a user starting with `Mike` you have to use `Mike*` in the filter syntax; it's just a shorthand to allow you to specify a wildcard without needing to escape it.

So:

```
public List<String> findByName(String Name) {
LdapQuery query = query().where("objectclass").is("top")
        .and("Name").like(Name + "*");

return ldapTemplate.search(query, new NameAttributesMapper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding a wildcard after the name:

```
public List<String> findByName(String Name) {
LdapQuery query = query().where("objectclass").is("top")
        .and("Name").like(Name + "*");

return ldapTemplate.search(query, new NameAttributesMapper());
}
```